# Translation phrases for email from english

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

**1. "...write Bachelor thesis under your supervision..."**

*I would like to translate it as: unter Betreuung der  Bachelorarbeit schreiben

**2. Coould you please check the folowing sentense?**

Wahrscheinlich erinnern Sie ihn. Sie haben mich mit ihm kennengelernt, als wir nach Muenchen während meines Praktikums in ihre Firma gegangen sind.

**Eng version:** Probable you remember him. We met with him when we went to Muenchen during my internship in your company

Comment: First of all use the German spelling correction of your software! That will fix the first 5 mistakes, including a is not ä!

Comment: In your context, supervision is "Betreuung". Anweisung is more an order. "Kennenlernen" requires "mich" (accusative). "Wenn" is direct translation of English which is wrong, so use "als" instead. There is no word "Bacherarbeit", please use a dictionary! ;)

Comment: @äüö I have used Duden, it fixed only 1 mistake

Comment: Copy the text for instance to a new document file in Open Office or Word and the software will mark the spelling mistakes with a red sinuous line, automatically.

Comment: Take attention "Bachelorarbeit" is not masculine. It can't be "der" in accusative.

Comment: @äüö i thought about Genitiv for Bachelorarbeit

Comment: @äüö word doesnt mark  "Betreuung der Bachelorarbeit " as mistake

Comment: _Wahrscheinlich erinnern Sie sich noch an ihn. Wir haben ihn kennengelernt, als wir während meines Praktikums in Ihrer Firma nach Ilmenau gefahren sind._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unter Betreuung **der** Bachelorarbeit schreiben

*Die Arbeit* is feminine and so *die Bachelorarbeit* is, too. This means *der* indicates the dative or genitive case. This marks *die Bachelorarbeit* either as the receiver of the *möchte schreiben* action, or the owner or an attribute of *Betreuung*. For *die Bachelorarbeit*, this doesn't make too much sense. Let's use another feminine noun, *die Behörde* instead:

> Ich möchte unter Betreuung **der** Behörde schreiben.

*I want to write **to the** office under supervision.* (assuming dative is meant)

*I want to write under supervision **of the** office.* (assuming genitive is meant)

To express *Bachelorarbeit* being the thing you wanted to write, you had to use an accusative marker instead:

> Ich möchte unter Betreuung **die** Bachelorarbeit schreiben.

---

> Wahrscheinlich erinnern Sie ihn.

You cannot use *erinnern* this way in German. The accusative object is **the person who remembers**, not the thing remembered. It sometimes takes a genitive object but  this means the same as the verb *gedenken* and is reserved for remembering killed people.

Using an accusative object with *erinnern* as the thing remembered is an anglicism and runs a chill in my spine because of *both*.

> Wahrscheinlich erinnern Sie **sich** an ihn.

*Sich* is a reflexive pronoun. The person who remembers. The subject. The thing remembered is put as a prepositional object with *an+accusative*.

---

> Sie haben mich mit ihm kennengelernt, …

*You met me being with him.*

Huh? WHAT? Well, because *mit ihm* indicates a relationship. I'm pretty sure that's not the case. You have to avoid this phrase then.

> Sie haben mich dort kennengelernt, …

---

> …, als wir nach Ilmenau während meines Praktikums in ihre Firma gegangen sind.

*…, as we walked into your company during my internship after the Ilmenau incident.*

*Gehen* means *to walk* in German and there are only a few exceptions when it means *to go*. The *nach Ilmenau* part has to be aligned to the other place *in ihre Firma*. If you put it in front of another time expression, you are talking about a time, not a place. But I think you talk about being at this company rather than going to it, so it should read

> …, als wir während meines Praktikums in ihrer Firma in Ilmenau waren.

Comment: I understood Nani wants to write to a third person about a guy who was there with Nani.

Comment: Yes. I understood that, too, but only from context.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile you've fixed all spelling mistakes by yourself. So far so good.

Now the grammar problems:

1. Writing something means that something is the object. "Schreiben" requires the object to be in accusative. So it's "die Bachelorarbeit" here since "Die Arbeit" is feminine. Writing what (accusative) to someone (dative).
2. The verb "erinnern" works differently than in English. It's reflexive if it happens in someones mind, so it requires "sich", which means you actually say in German something like "remember in yourself", you know what I mean. Furthermore "erinnern" also requires the preposition "an" for the object to remember, which means "on" in English. So it is: "Wahrscheinlich erinnern Sie sich an ihn.". The second sentence is almost right, but obviously you mean "Ihrer" (genitive of "Ihre"), the polite version of "your", and you don't mean "ihre" which translates from English "her".

Comment: 2. I have made then a mistake with translation. I woudl like to write smth else ( i have added eng version).

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the grammar to you